# Django NoReverseMatch error for deleted view and url

Tags: django, django-views

When I run the server for my local project, the browser displays the following:

"""
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'posts.views.showusers' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Request Method: GET
"""

Note that "posts" is an App. I have  deleted anything related to showusers in  posts/views.py and posts/urls.py. Why do I keep on seeing that message?

Comment: did u remove 'Posts' app from installed apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in your templates that you're not using the `url` template tag for `showusers`.